# Jquery CarouselLite

Tags: jquery, carousel

I have a jQuery carousel within a wordpress template page that builds products into "slides", where each product is the slide within the carousel. My specific problem is that not ALL the products that are being created by my loop are being shown, but they are being created in the DOM. BUT, when i turn on "element information" on my toolbar in firefox, it brings in all the other products that are being listed, even the ones that are "hiding". I reasonably sure this is NOT a CSS issue, but I could be wrong, and i'm not showing any errors that are prevalent when I validate. So I'm wondering if anybody has any idea of what is causing it to do this
? Is it perhaps a version of jQuery issue? you can view the site at 
http://healthylifestyleandspirit.thedesigngrouponline.com/online-store/ to see for yourself what the issue is.

Comment: Your source code shows four unique products. Can you double check that the server code is returning all products? Checking with firebug I only see cloned list items probably used by the carousel to create some circular effect.

Comment: Thanks, But I wound up fixing it. The error was in the carousel's code, which is an *now* unsupported carousel with a lot of bugs.